# ExtJs - constructor overriding my instances

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I use ExtJs 4.1 and DeftJs.

Some class is defined with a constructor like that:

```
Ext.define( 'A.helper.Report', {
  config: {
     conf     : null,
     viewMain : null
  },
  constructor: function( oConfig ) {
     this.conf = oConfig.conf;
     this.viewMain = oConfig.viewMain;
     this.initConfig( oConfig );
  }
...
```

Now, I create several instances of this class like that:

```
var class1 = Ext.create( 'A.helper.Report', {
   conf: someValue,
   viewMain: someObject
} );

var class2 = Ext.create( 'A.helper.Report', {
   conf: otherValue,
   viewMain: otherObject
} );
```

When using these instances, although giving them different `oConfig` data, both `class1` and `class2` now have the data of the 2nd `oConfig`.

So when calling `this.conf` in both instances, I get `someValue`.

How can I keep the data of already created instances?

---

**Solution:**

I wrote

```
Ext.define( 'A.helper.Report', {
   ... 
  references: {}
  ...
```

and put my instances in there, overriding old instances.

Switched to `references: null` helped.

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful to not messing around with prototype objects...

**Rewritten answer**

You are doing it the wrong way.

See this working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/b2WA4/)**

```
Ext.define('A.helper.Report', {
     config: {
         conf     : null,
         viewMain : null
     },
     constructor: function(cfg) {
         this.initConfig(cfg);
     }
});


var class1 = Ext.create('A.helper.Report',{
    conf: 66,
    viewMain: 'Bear'
});

var class2 = Ext.create('A.helper.Report',{
    conf: 88,
    viewMain: 'Eagle'
});

class1.getConf(); // 66
class1.getViewMain(); // Bear
class2.getConf(); // 88
class2.getViewMain(); // Eagle
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Could I fix this by using other class concepts? Could you please give an example/ref on clone & apply?

Comment: Hi sra, tried your approach, but still same data. I tried also using `initComponent()` but it does not get called at all on creation.

Comment: @Indianer I have completely rewritten my answer and added a working example